# Any clue for the following exercises?

Tags: calculus

There are a few HW exercises which I am not sure how to solve. any help?

1. Prove that, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \geq 1$, $$(e^x\sin x)^{(n)} = 2^{\frac{n}{2}}e^x\sin\left(x+n\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
2. For every $x>0,~~n \geq 1$, $$(x^n\log x)^{(n)}=n!\left(\log x+1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried induction over $n$?

Comment: I will try. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since
   $$
   e^x\sin x=\Im e^xe^{ix}=\Im e^{(1+i)x}, 
   $$
   it follows that
   $$
   (e^x\sin x)^{(n)}=\Im\left[(1+i)^ne^{(1+i)x}\right]=\Im\left[e^x(\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac\pi4})^ne^{ix}\right]=\Im\left[2^{\frac{n}{2}}e^xe^{i(x+n\frac\pi4)}\right]=2^{\frac{n}{2}}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right).
   $$
2. Setting
   $$
   f_n(x)=(x^n\ln x)^{(n)},
   $$
   we have
   \begin{eqnarray}
   f_n(x)&=&[(x^n\ln x)']^{(n-1)}=\left[nx^{n-1}\ln x+\frac{x^n}{x}\right]^{(n-1)}=n(x^{n-1}\ln x)^{(n-1)}+(x^{n-1})^{(n-1)}\\
   &=&nf_{n-1}(x)+(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\ldots2\cdot1=nf_{n-1}(x)+(n-1)!\\
   &=&nf_{n-1}(x)+\frac{n!}{n}=n\left[(n-1)f_{n-2}(x)+\frac{(n-1)!}{n-1}\right]+\frac{n!}{n}\\
   &=&n(n-1)f_{n-2}(x)+\frac{n!}{n-1}+\frac{n!}{n}\\
   &\vdots&\\
   &=&n(n-1)\ldots2f_1(x)+\frac{n!}{2}+\frac{n!}{3}+\ldots+\frac{n!}{n}\\
   &=&n!(x\ln x)'+n!\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}\\
   &=&n!(\ln x+1)+n!\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}\\
   &=&n!\left(\ln x+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right)
   \end{eqnarray}